# Email validation not working correctly using javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my email address validation code using JavaScript. The alert messages are correctly working but when I submit giving a valid email address it alerts 'Please provide a valid email address'. Please help me.

```
if(email=="")
{
    alert("Enter emailid");
    $("#email").focus();
    return false;
}

else if(email!="")
{
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if (!filter.test(email.value)) 
    {   
        //alert(email)
        //alert(filter.test(email.value)) 
        alert('Please provide a valid email address');
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What e-mail address are you testing with? Also: what's the value of ``email`` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: https://emailtester.pieterhordijk.com/test-pattern/NjQ just saying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function ValidateEmail(){

var email = $('#txtemail').val();
if(email=="")
{
    alert("Enter emailid");
    $("#txtemail").focus();
    return false;
}

else if(email!="")
{
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if (!filter.test(email)) 
    {   
        //alert(email)
        //alert(filter.test(email.value)) 
        alert('Please provide a valid email address');
        $('#txtemail').focus();
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Call the function `ValidateEmail` on the onclick event of your button. And also please note that you are doing something wrong with this line

```
if (!filter.test(email.value))
```

change this to be

```
if (!filter.test(email))
```

hope this helps.

Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BQssY/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question...but can you not use HTML5 email input for this purpose? Why write javascript code for email validation when the browser can handle it? Use something like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email">
```

There are many advantages to using this including on-screen keyboard to match it (adds @ and .com options).

For different types of HTML5 input types, refer this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Comment: Please, do not quote w3schools. It is known to be inaccurate. See http://www.w3fools.com/.

Comment: @EtienneMiret Read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120621/w3fools-alternatives

Comment: I was linking you to w3fools, not the OP, so next time you link to a better resource. But OK, for completeness, let me link to the [HTML5 Specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html#attr-input-type) about different input types.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in your code, which makes the alert to display.

Please look for this line in your code

```
if (!filter.test(email.value))
```

and replace with

```
if (!filter.test(email))
```

Variable Email holds the value of Email field of your form.

And another change would be, look for this line

```
email.focus();
```

and change this one to

```
$("#email").focus();
```